# Conditional formatting stops macro from running all the way

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have some conditional formatting together with a module, that for some reason prevents my macros from running all the way through.

`=NOT(TestColor(E8))` is my conditional format, checked off with 'Stop if true' and works together with this module;

```
Function TestColor (MyRange As Range) As Boolean
If Range (MyRange.Address).Interior.Pattern = x1None Then TestColor = True
End function
```

This gives me the ability to manually color cells that is otherwise colored by conditional formatting. (I didn't write this specific code, it was something i found).

However, i've found out that this also prevents any macros i make (relative or not) from running all the way through, meaning if i make a macro that creates a new row and then copies the row above, it will simply just create a new row and stop there as if it's finished, with no error messages popping up either.
I know that this specific conditional format is what causes my macros to not work, as they work as intended if i delete it.

Is there a way i can get macros to work without having to delete the formatting? Or is there another way to be able to manually color cells that is being colored by conditional formatting?

Comment: Without knowing the project: but propably it's worth re-factoring the inital conditional formatting so that you don't need this "hack".

Comment: May or may not be related to your issue,  but `Range (MyRange.Address). ...` is an awful piece of code.  What it's actually doing is referring the celll referenced by MyRange, but on the ActiveSheet, regardless of which sheet MyRange is on.  Use `MyRange.Interior.Pattern` inste5

Comment: @chrisneilsen while the change you suggested does seem to still allow me to color the formatted cells, the macros does not work still.

Comment: @Ike I would have done this from the start if i could. The conditional formatting i have in the sheet is essentially coloring the weekends in a calendar gray, but users need to be able to color each day yellow as to mark for days accounted for.

Comment: You mean they will want to color a saturday or sunday? That won't work. But propably you can set a grey font via conditional formatting - and the user sets the background color if necessary (or vice versa). That would work